# TwinCAT OPC UA: Setting individual Publish-Rate using Direct Access

Tags: plc, twincat, st

I have configured a Twincat OPC UA server and need a fast cyclic data exchange of some variables (~400 bytes) with 1000Hz. If I set the publishing rate for all variables in the xml to 1ms, the CPU is 100% busy and the communication does not work. Is it possible to set the publishing rate individually via an attribute for example?

```
{attribute 'OPC.UA.DA' := '1'}
//{datarate := 1000Hz}
CriticalData : Struct_of_CriticalData;
//{datarate := 10Hz} 
UncriticalData : Struct_of_UncriticalData;
{attribute 'OPC.UA.DA' := '0'}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpcServerConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UaServerConfig>
    <MaxRequestAge>0</MaxRequestAge>
    <MaxSessionCount>100</MaxSessionCount>
    <MinSessionTimeout>10000</MinSessionTimeout>
    <MaxSessionTimeout>3600000</MaxSessionTimeout>
    <MaxBrowseContinuationPoints>0</MaxBrowseContinuationPoints>
    <MaxHistoryContinuationPoints>0</MaxHistoryContinuationPoints>
    <MinPublishingInterval>1</MinPublishingInterval>
    <MaxPublishingInterval>0</MaxPublishingInterval>
    <MinKeepAliveInterval>5000</MinKeepAliveInterval>
    <MinSubscriptionLifetime>10000</MinSubscriptionLifetime>
    <MaxSubscriptionLifetime>0</MaxSubscriptionLifetime>
    <MaxRetransmitionQueueSize>10</MaxRetransmitionQueueSize>
    <MaxNotificationsPerPublish>0</MaxNotificationsPerPublish>
    <MaxDataQueueSize>100</MaxDataQueueSize>
    <MaxEventQueueSize>10000</MaxEventQueueSize>
    <MaxSubscriptionCount>0</MaxSubscriptionCount>
    <MaxMonitoredItemCount>0</MaxMonitoredItemCount>
    <MaxMonitoredItemPerSubscriptionCount>0</MaxMonitoredItemPerSubscriptionCount>
    <AvailableLocaleIds>
      <LocaleId>en</LocaleId>
    </AvailableLocaleIds>
    <AvailableServerProfiles>
      <ServerProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UAProfile/Server/StandardUA</ServerProfileUri>
      <ServerProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UAProfile/Server/DataAccess</ServerProfileUri>
      <ServerProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UAProfile/Server/Methods</ServerProfileUri>
      <ServerProfileUri>http://opcfoundation.org/UAProfile/Server/EventSubscription</ServerProfileUri>
    </AvailableServerProfiles>
    <IsAuditActivated>false</IsAuditActivated>
    <RedundancySettings>
      <RedundancySupport>None</RedundancySupport>
    </RedundancySettings>
    <MinSupportedSampleRate>0</MinSupportedSampleRate>
    <AvailableSamplingRates>
      <SamplingRate>1</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>2</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>3</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>4</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>5</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>6</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>7</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>8</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>9</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>10</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>15</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>20</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>25</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>30</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>35</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>40</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>45</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>50</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>60</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>70</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>80</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>90</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>100</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>150</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>200</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>250</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>300</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>350</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>400</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>450</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>500</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>550</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>600</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>650</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>700</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>750</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>800</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>850</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>900</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>950</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>1000</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>2000</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>5000</SamplingRate>
      <SamplingRate>10000</SamplingRate>
    </AvailableSamplingRates>
</OpcServerConfig>
```

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a solution myself by adding a `MaxPublishingInterval` greater than `0` in the `Server-xml`.

I am not sure, if it works, since now the PC is the limiting factor...

```
<MaxPublishingInterval>200</MaxPublishingInterval>
```